# Trouble Mounting Azure Storage Account File Share into Azure Container App Postgres Image Due to Permission Issues

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, mount, azure-container-apps

I'm encountering issues mounting the File share of my Azure Storage Account into my Azure Container App running a Postgres image, with the goal of making the data in the container persistent. I can successfully mount the File share, and I can see the files within the container. However, when attempting to mount the File share to the Postgres directory, I'm facing permission problems. Found a similar question here but it is 3 years old and does not relate to Azure Container Apps in particular:

[Deploying Postgres database on azure Container Instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980940/deploying-postgres-database-on-azure-container-instance)

I've noticed that when using the PGDATA env variable to set the data directory of the database to /fish for example in the container, the permissions change slightly from postgres:postgres to postgres:root.

I suspect that the mount point is owned by the root user, whereas the database requires it to be owned by the postgres user. How can I resolve this permission mismatch to ensure a successful mount into the Postgres directory within the Azure Container App? Any insights or guidance on adjusting ownership or handling permissions would be greatly appreciated.

How can I resolve this permission mismatch? Any ideas for a fix or work around are welcome.

Logs:

```
initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/fish": Operation not permitted

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".

chmod: /fish: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
initdb: error: could not change permissions of directory "/fish": Operation not permitted

The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".

chmod: /fish: Operation not permitted
```

This is the normal permissions reminder from initdb. So, use a named volume instead of a bind volume.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

This will create a named volume that is not mounting a location from your host system and causing the permissions to go wrong. For more information, you can refer to the links below:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1780634/postgres-docker-error-data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-has-wrong-owner
- https://forums.docker.com/t/data-directory-var-lib-postgresql-data-has-wrong-ownership-on-linux/97057